# What is Informatica's equivalent to Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio, or is there?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, informatica-powercenter

I'm used to work with MS Sql Server Information Services (`SSIS`) and MS Sql Server Management Studio (`SSMS`), and now I'm working with Informatica's PowerCenter Express Developer (`PC Express`) for training purposes.

PC Express is the equivalent of SSIS. I wonder what's PowerCenter's equivalent to SSMS. Or is there?

What is Informatica's equivalent to Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informatica's Workflow Manager is the closest you could get, but this is more like viewing the "SQL Server Agents" part of the Informatica world to see schedules, jobs, steps etc.